# Trouble understanding return statement in Ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion

I don't understand why the code below is not returning the `rate` variable. The weird thing is that right above the `return` statement there is a `puts` statement that actually does print out the right value for `rate`.

```
def irr(lower_guess, higher_guess, increment, *amounts)
  rate = lower_guess
  precision_level = 0.1
  while rate <= higher_guess
    present_value = present_value_of_series(rate, *amounts)
    if present_value < 0
      puts "in if 1" #debug
      if present_value >= -precision_level
        puts rate
        return rate
      else
        irr((rate-increment), rate, increment/10, *amounts)
        break
      end
    else
      rate += increment
    end
  end
end
```

Sample method call:

```
irr(0.0001, 0.50, 0.01, -11000, 1966.63, 1959.37, 1952.13, 1944.88, 1937.6399999999999, 1930.3999999999999)
```

Edit:
Added sample method call

Edit 2: I have applied the solution proposed by @Mark Reed, and now it works:

```
def irr(lower_guess, higher_guess, increment, *amounts)
  rate = lower_guess
  precision_level = 0.1
  while rate <= higher_guess
    present_value = present_value_of_series(rate, *amounts)
    if present_value < 0
      if present_value >= -precision_level
        break
      else
        rate = irr((rate-increment), rate, increment/10, *amounts)        
      end
    else
      rate += increment
    end
  end
  return rate
end
```

Comment: can you also show how you're using the method? Which parameters are you passing?

Comment: You expect the code to return some value for `rate`. But what is it actually doing? Are you getting an error? Is it running until you force quit?

Comment: tompave: added a sample method call

Comment: thohl: I am getting a blank line in IRB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either `return` the result of the recursive call or set `rate` to it.

```
return irr((rate-increment), rate, increment/10, *amounts)
```

Comment: That has solved the problem, thanks (see code above). I am still trying to understand why, though.

Answer (score 1):

The `return rate` line is not the only return point of this method.It might go to the end, in which case, the return value is implicitely the last expression (the `while` loop).

Change it to:

```
def irr(lower_guess, higher_guess, increment, *amounts)
  #...
  while rate <= higher_guess
    #...
  end
  rate  # here
end
```

Comment: Isn't there also an issue with the `break` statement? If control returns from a recursive call to `irr` and hits that break statement, shouldn't `break` force the function to return `nil`?

Comment: not with @yu-hao's change.  the `break` will just break out of the `while` loop and then return the value of `rate`.

Comment: @Yu Hao: Moving `return rate` to the end yields a wrong value for `rate`. The value I am getting is the rate at the first run of the recursive function call (`irr((rate-increment), rate, increment/10, *amounts)`). The value I need is the one generated after the last run of the recursive  function call.